# A continuously updating DNS registry on the local machine

Tags: dns

Would maintaining a continuously updating DNS registry on the local machine of the World Wide Web be an overkill with privacy and speed in mind?

What would be the overheads that would make this approch useless?

Comment: What do you mean by "continuously updating"?

Comment: around the world new Ip's may come up with new Domain mapping. So lets say the registry gets updated continuously with all the new IP-Domain mapping or updated IP-Domain mapping.

Comment: (That is almost impossible, but also) What would even be the practical benefit of having that?

Comment: That's my question exactly. I think Privacy would be the main benefit, speed too maybe.